# How to split data into multiple outputs files based on value of a given column

Tags: talend

**Using Talend Open Studio for Data integration**

How can I split one Excel file into multiple outputs based on values of given column ?

**Example**

```
Example of data in input.xlsx :

    ID; Category
    1; AAA
    2; AAA
    3; BBB
    4; CCC

Example of output files :

     AAA.xlsx contains ID 1 and 2
     BBB.xslx contains ID 3
     CCC.xslx contains ID 4
```

**What I tried ?**

> tfilelist-->tinputexcel-->tuniqrows-->tflowtoiterate-->tfileinputexcel-->tfilterow-->tlogrow

In order to perform these actions :

- Browse a folder of Excel files
- Iterate to Open Excel file
- Get uniques values in Excel files (on column used for the split)
- Iterate to generate splitted files with the unique values and tfilterow to filter Excel file and that's where I get an error about Garbage Collector

*Exception in component tFileInputExcel_4 (automatisation_premed)
java.io.IOException: GC overhead limit exceeded
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded*

[Talend's job diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldEZ8.png)

Do someone have an idea to optimize this talend workflow and solve GC error ? Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think we must not iterate on an Excel Input as openning twice the same file is a problem both on Windows and in designed job so a workaround should be :

[Talend diagram for the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTrYy.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to tackle this type of thing in Talend. One approach is to store the Excel file somewhere after loading (Database, CSV, Hash, etc).

An alternative approach is to aggregate -> iterate -> normalize the data like so:
[image: JobCanvas]

**In tAggregateRow you want to group by the field containing the 'base' of your file name (Category in this case)**:
[image: Aggregation]

**The aggregate function should be 'list' (with an appropriate delimiter not already contained in your Id column**:
[image: Delimiter]

**Feed the aggregated output into a tFlowToIterate to loop over each Category**:
[image: Iteration]

**tFixedFlow can be used to output each of the aggregates to an independent flow**:
[image: Feeding Rows]

**Use tNormalize to dump the single Category row into one row per Id by normalizing the 'list' column**:
[image: Normalization]

**Set the tFileOutputExcel file name to be the current iterations Category as defined in tFlowToIterate**:
[image: Output Component]

**Final result is one file per Category with one row per Id**:
[image: File List]

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Thank you for answering I will take time to try this way with a csv staging file